# how to take the year using date stored in DataBase:

Tags: sql, datetime, stored-procedures, datetimepicker

how to take the year using date stored in DataBase:

in Sql query ?? ????

eg date stored as

2010-04-29 15:53:09.577

how to get the year in stored procedure to check whether the year i pass and the year stored in database are same

Comment: It would help to know which database management system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That depends on the database. Try using the `YEAR` function.

E.g.,

```
IF YEAR(MyDateColumn) = @year ...
```

Answer (score 1):

To check a single value you can use the `year` function to extract the year from a date.

If you are comparing a year to a date in all records in a table, you should instead convert the year to a span of dates:

```
select SomeFields
from TheTable
where TheDate >= '2010-01-01' and TheDate < '2011-01-01'
```

It's a lot faster to compare the date values, as an index can be used. If you do a `year` function call on each value from the table, it can't use the index.